# Safari and IE9 min-height taking precedence over height

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using Safari 5.0.5 and IE9 in Windows for testing a website. In the CSS, I have:

```
#contentarea { 
  background-image:url('../images/img.jpg'); 
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
  background-position: right top;    
  background-size:100% auto;
  min-height:650px;
```

}

In jQuery, I set a height like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var vertHeight = $('.innerpage #vBar').outerHeight(true);
  $('.innerpage #contentarea').css({'height':vertHeight });
});
```

The `height` is correctly set in the `style` attribute of the div. However these browsers seem to always render `min-height` value first even when the `height` is less than `min-height`. In other words, `height` is completely ignored.

I need `min-height` in the CSS so that when it first renders the div, it needs to have that minimum height as jquery sometimes does not seem to work on first page load.

Comment: If the `height` is less than the `min-height`, then the shortest height that the element is **should** be the `min-height`'s value ... why not use jQuery to just update the `min-height`?

Answer (score 0):

By definition, The [min-height](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_min-height.asp) property always overrides both height and max-height to prevent the value of the height property from becoming smaller than min-height.

You should review your element height and find out what the real minimum value is you should use this value for your page so it does not interfere with your JQuery code.